# How to solve "object required" exception in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have written a simple Javascript function as follows:

```
function loginValidate(){
   var rValue = true;
   var username = document.getElementById("username").value; 
   var password = document.getElementById("password").value;

   if(username=="" || password==""){
      alert('Empty field');
      rValue = false;
   }
   return rValue;
   //alert('hi');
}
```

When I hit the submit button I am getting the error as: 
**Object required : loginValidate.js line 3 character 3**

I am getting the error on both **IE 8 and FF 10** but it works fine in Eclipse internal browser.

Am I missing something? Kindly help, thanks in advance.

Comment: `document.getElementById` got nothing, so cannot have `.value`

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing that when that function runs, `document.getElementById("username").value;` is not finding an element.  As a result `document.getElementById("username")` returns `null` and `null.value` throws an exception, since `null` is not allowed to have properties.

Exactly why that is not finding your element depends on your HTML and when this JS snippets runs.

Answer (score 1):

try to put this text to debug

alert(document.getElementById("username"));
alert(document.getElementById("password"));

if it said htmlxxxelement, then it found something.
where xxx is like div, table, or input
if it said undefined, or null, then it doesnt found the HTML control. you need to check the spelling. or create the control somewhere.